# Responsive Google Donut chart with responsive Pie hole?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to make my google charts responsive and this help me out a lot:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <div id="chart_div" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
</div>
```

as I am using bootstrap as well. But with my PieChart I added an overlay in the center piehole. How do I make the piehole overlay responsive as well, like in the code preview it was in the center but now it is way off and resizing the browser doesn't make it better.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.45,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```css
#pieHoleOverlay {
color:white;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 25px!important;
}
.pieHole {
display: block;
    background: black;
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 75px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 140px !important;
    left: 145px !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       
       
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <div id="piechart" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
  <div id="pieHoleOverlay" class="pieHole">test 99</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I came here because I thought there was pie and donuts.

Answer (score 2):

you can position the overlay when the chart's `'ready'` event fires...

use chart method --> `getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox(id)`

this will give you the bounds for the id you pass

to find the bounds of the chart itself...

`chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox('chart')`

to find the bounds of the first pie slice, etc...

`chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox('slice#0')`

use the bounds from each slice to calculate the total height and width of the chart (slices only)
then multiply by the `pieHole` chart option (`0.45`)

also, to make the chart responsive, it needs to be re-drawn when the window resizes

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    pieHole: 0.45,
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('piechart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
  var overlay = document.getElementById('pieHoleOverlay');

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartArea = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('chart');
    var pieLabels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var pieHoleWidth;

    var sliceBounds = {
      bottom: null,
      top: null,
      left: null,
      right: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    };
    for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var slice = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('slice#' + i);
      var sliceBottom = slice.top + slice.height;
      var sliceRight = slice.left + slice.width;
      sliceBounds.bottom = Math.max(sliceBottom, (sliceBounds.bottom || sliceBottom));
      sliceBounds.right = Math.max(sliceRight, (sliceBounds.right || sliceRight));
      sliceBounds.top = Math.min(slice.top, (sliceBounds.top || slice.top));
      sliceBounds.left = Math.min(slice.left, (sliceBounds.left || slice.left));
    }
    sliceBounds.height = sliceBounds.bottom - sliceBounds.top;
    sliceBounds.width = sliceBounds.right - sliceBounds.left;

    if (data.getNumberOfRows() > 0) {
      overlay.className = 'pieHole';
      pieHoleWidth = (sliceBounds.width * options.pieHole);
      overlay.style.left = (sliceBounds.left + (sliceBounds.width / 2) - (pieHoleWidth / 2)) + 'px';
      overlay.style.width = pieHoleWidth + 'px';
      overlay.style.height = overlay.style.width;
      overlay.style.top = (((chartArea.height - chartArea.top) / 2) - (pieHoleWidth / 2)) + 'px';
      overlay.style.lineHeight = overlay.style.height;
      if (pieLabels.length > 0) {
        overlay.style.fontSize = pieLabels[0].getAttribute('font-size') + 'px';
      }
    } else {
      overlay.className = 'hidden';
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.pieHole {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <div id="piechart" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
  <div id="pieHoleOverlay" class="hidden">test 99</div>
</div>
```